# SQL Organising Data by Date

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have data for 7 days pumping into the same table called '7days_data' until on the 7th day the data is then archived off to a history table. 
My question is, when all the data is in the 7days_data table what is the best way of writing a query just to get that days data out that i need (just to see an indivudual day and not all seven days).
I have tried the Like operator '%date%' but fails. The date is in the following format 2015-02-13 21:03:12.337 is in a column called 'dateAdded'

Comment: can you provide sample data and sample query?  what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your date is `DateTime` column, you will need to either use `>=` and `<` or you can convert it to `Date` in your query.

```
SELECT <fields>
FROM 7days_data
WHERE dateAdded >= '2/18/2015' 
AND dateAdded < '2/19/2015'
```

That will ensure that the `dateAdded` is some time on 2/18/2015.

Alternate:

```
SELECT <fields>
FROM 7days_data
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, dateAdded) = '2/18/2015'
```

Comment: You probably want to add the time stamp on the end of it or you may miss some of the data so more like `>= '2/18/2015 11:59:59'`

Comment: The `>= '2/18/2015'` will catch anything on 2/18, and the `< '2/19/2015'` will make sure it cuts off at 2/18 at 11:59:59.

Comment: `>= '2/18/2015 11:59:59' AND < '2/19/2015'` is a *very small* range :)